# Ajuda Com Relacionamento entre 3 Tabelas #Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relacionamento, active-record, erb

gostaria da ajuda de vocês nesse problema abaixo

Tenho 3 Tabelas:

```
Product           Purshase       Supplier
supplier_id      product_id        name


class Purshase < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :supplier
    has_many :purshase
end

class Supplier< ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
end
```

Gostaria de apresentar assim na minha view: **purchase.product.supplier.name**

Alguém poderia me ajudar ? Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Para fazer algo assim cada produto deveria ter um fornecedor apenas, e assim a relação teria que ser `has_one :supplier` e não `has_many :supplier`. Qual é situação correta do negócio, isto é, o produto pode ter vários fornecedores ou apenas um?

Answer (score 0):

Vamos seguir pelo caminho mais simples: Um fornecedor (supplier) tem vários produtos (products) e o produto pode ter várias vendas (purchase).

```
rails g model Supplier name:string
rails g model Product  name:string supplier:references
rails g model Purchase name:string product:references

class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :purchases, through: :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :supplier
  has_many :purchases
end

class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Agora vamos brincar no console:

```
> sup = Supplier.create name: "Fornecedor 1"
=> #<Supplier id: 1, name: "Fornecedor 1", created_at: "2017-07-14 14:54:02", updated_at: "2017-07-14 14:54:02">
> sup.products << Product.create(name: "Produto 1")
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Product id: 1, name: "Produto 1", supplier_id: 1, created_at: "2017-07-14 14:54:45", updated_at: "2017-07-14 14:54:45">]>
> sup.products.first.purchases << Purchase.create(name: "Compra 1")
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Purchase id: 1, name: "Compra 1", product_id: 1, created_at: "2017-07-14 14:55:36", updated_at: "2017-07-14 14:55:36">]>
```

Então temos:

```
Purchase.first
=> #<Purchase id: 1, name: "Compra 1", product_id: 1, created_at: "2017-07-14 14:57:11", updated_at: "2017-07-14 14:57:11"> 
> Purchase.first.product
=> #<Product id: 1, name: "Produto 1", supplier_id: 1, created_at: "2017-07-14 14:57:07", updated_at: "2017-07-14 14:57:07"> 
> Purchase.first.product.supplier
=> #<Supplier id: 1, name: "Fornecedor 1", created_at: "2017-07-14 14:57:03", updated_at: "2017-07-14 14:57:03"> 
> Purchase.first.product.supplier.name
=> "Fornecedor 1"
```